# Search for a phrase using mongoose, express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Following the documentation of mongodb [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#search-for-a-phrase), I'm trying to search for something using mongoose while using the search query from express, my code is this

```
collection_name.find{$text: { $search: req.query.search} }
```

but this returns the wrong set of data from the db (since it isn't taking the query as a phrase)

I'm trying to take this

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "\"coffee shop\"" } } )
```

(which is the example from the documentation, and it was giving the results that I wanted)

into this:

```
collection_name.find( { $text: { $search: "\"req.query.search\"" } } )
```

but taking the req.query.search as a variable instead of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use backtick character to construct search term like this:

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: `"${req.query.search}"` } } )
```

Comment: @LeoPolanco now it works, please see the updated answer.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I guess you meant like in the updated answer, right?

Comment: You shouldn't need the \\

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes that also worked, and it is cleaner, I will update the answer, thank you.

Comment: @LeoPolanco JohnnyHK suggested a cleaner syntax, better to use it. Check please the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, greets